# Angular 6 difference between .env vs environment.ts

Tags: angular, environment-variables, angular6

I generated a project from https://mean.io. But I am not sure what the difference is between (.env and .env.example) and (environment.ts and environment.prod.ts).

Where should I store all of my config data, secrets, and keys?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should store them in the environment.ts

**`environment.ts`**
If you refer environment object properties in your Angular project, during development mode i.e. ng serve or ng build all values shall be read from this file.

**`environment.prod.ts`**
When you build your application for production mode using ng build --prod in that case, all values of environment.ts file shall get overridden by environment.prod.ts files.

The above variables are related to your Angular application. Whereas .env and .env.example are for the Laravel application.

**`.env`** as it should be is out of version controlled and ignored when you push your project to any repository. This is for your own safety.

**`.env.example`** which contains very generic information is copied as .env on fresh install and a few changes made. ex APP_KE

Comment: Then what is .env and .env.example used for?

Comment: That is for the laravel app . nothing to do with angular

Comment: The Github project that was provided by the poster doesn't have any reference to a Laravel app. The .env file is used to replace environment variables in the node express API.

Answer (score 2):

`environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` are used in your angular application for loading different variables depending on where the application is running.

`ng serve` will run the application with the `environemnt.ts` file.
`ng serve --prod` will run the application with the `environment.prod.ts` file.

A good example of this would be for an API url. In development you would use `http//:localhost:<port>` where as in production the url might be `www.<my-api>.com` you can use the different environment files to have these switch between builds.

Keep in mind that the angular environment file will be readable to any user on you website. It's a bad idea to keep usernames, passwords or api keys in the `environment.ts` or `environment.prod.ts` files.

The `.env` file is used to store environment variables for the node/express API. This code runs on a server. the `require('dotenv').config();` line in the `server/config/config.js` file is where the file is loaded. Dotenv will populate environment variables that are accessed using `process.env.<My_Environment_Variable_Name>` using the .env file.